# Generative Syntax and French

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe, linguistique

Theoretical linguistics seems to be dominated by the Chomskian transformational generative grammar and its offshoots. I am wondering whether these theories are generally accepted by the French linguists and/or whether there are popular alternatives.

I will appreciate comments on this subject. More specifically:

- Are transformational generative syntax theories popular among the French linguists?
- Do these theories encounter specific problems when treating French and other Romance languages? What kind of problems?
- What are the alternative theories and where could I learn more about them?

Feel free to post in either English or French.

**Note:** Here is a relevant book: *Foundations of French syntax* by Michael Allan Jones (Cambridge University Press, 1996). It is a grammar aimed at advanced learners of French which in the same time may serve as an introduction to transformational generative grammars as applied to this language.

Comment: From what I can remember when I was a student (late eighties, early nineties), the Chomskian school of linguistics had not made much progress in France.  The linguistic field was still dominated by structuralism going back to Saussure via Emile Benvéniste and Gustave Guillaume.  Funny when you consider the debt Chomsky himself felt he owed to Descartes and the Port-Royal logicians.

Comment: La linguistique chomskienne semble prendre parmi les philosophes qui s'intéressent à la philosophie du langage. Cf l'article de Paul Egré sur la " Philosophie du langage" dans Barberousse, Précis de Philosophie des sciences, accessible sur la Page personnelle de Paul Egré>Publications>Surveys

Answer (score 1):

Pas une réponse, mais un commentaire.

Traditionnellement, la grammaire française distingue entre nature et fonction.

Un mot a toujours la même nature ( adjectif, pronom, adverbe, article), mais il peut avoir différentes fonctions ( dans des phrases  différentes).

***En tant que français, ce qui me surprend dans la grammaire de Chomsky, c'est que les règles syntaxiques sont formulées en termes de " parties du discours" , c'est-à-dire, de nature.***

Par exemple :

Phrase --> Groupe nominal + Groupe verbal.

Or, il me semble que traditionnellement (depuis Aristote) , les " natures" ou " parties du discours" sont des catégories sémantiques, et non syntaxiques :

-nom --> désigne une substance ( première ou seconde)

-adjectif --> désigne un accident ( une " propriété" d'une substance)

-verbe --> désigne une relation d'inhérence ( v. être) ou une action ; renvoie au temps, etc.

Par ailleurs, on peut construire beaucoup de phrases en français dont le sujet n'est pas un groupe nominal , par exemple :

- ***Mentir*** est honteux.
- Rares sont ***ceux qui ont fait le tour du monde.***
- ***Que tu dises cela*** me tourmente.

Ainsi, dans la même perspective que vous, je me demandais quelle pouvait être la pertinence de la syntaxe de Chomsky pour le français.

J'ai posé une question en ce sens dans Linguistics Stack Exchange sans obtenir véritablement de réponse.

Comment: Je suis d'accord que les termes sont mal choisi et probablement cachent un problème plus profond. La groupe nominal peut être une phrase (*a clause* en anglais), ce qui prend compte de vos deux derniers exemples. *Mentir est honteux* utilise un infinitif comme un nom - en anglais on normalement utilise dans tels cas une forme qui finit en *-ing* (lying).